# API/syscall to read or list BSD/macOS file flags

Tags: files, permissions, macos, system-calls, bsd

I've learned that besides the standard *nix file *permissions*, macOS also has file *flags*, and that they originated with BSD Unix. macOS's set of such flags is:

> ```
> UF_NODUMP      Do not dump the file.
> UF_IMMUTABLE   The file may not be changed.
> UF_APPEND      The file may only be appended to.
> UF_OPAQUE      The directory is opaque when viewed through a union stack.
> UF_HIDDEN      The file or directory is not intended to be dis-played displayed played to the user.
> SF_ARCHIVED    The file has been archived.
> SF_IMMUTABLE   The file may not be changed.
> SF_APPEND      The file may only be appended to.
> ```

You can see these extra flags with an extra switch to ls, though the switch varies:

- `ls -lo` - BSD and perhaps older versions of macOS
- `ls -lO` - current versions of macOS

You can change the flags with the commands the `chflags` command: [FreeBSD man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chflags&sektion=1)

There are corresponding system calls `chflags`, `lchflags`, `fchflags` to change these flags: [macOS man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/fchflags.2.html)

But I can't seem to find a system call to *read* the flags. Surely `ls` calls some function to get them? The syscalls that can change them don't seem to be able to also return their current state.

What am I missing?

(If this belongs on StackOverflow then please feel free to move it there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flags can be read using [`stat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/stat.2.html) on macOS and BSDs; they appear in the `st_flags` field.

Comment: As as happened a few times before, I found this a few minutes after crafting my question here, which I did only after wasting over an hour searching for the answer. But it always seems better to reward somebody else for knowing the answer. I don't know why the Mac man pages for `chflags` don't mention `stat` in its "See also" section. But I see that the BSD man pages do.

Comment: Thanks! Going the other way, I found it amusing that the macOS `stat` page mentions `chflags`, but the OpenBSD one doesn’t...